# Flutter: I'm trying to wrap a Text widget with the expanded class but I get "the named parameter 'child' isn't defined" error

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, flutter-layout, user-experience

When I put "child: Text(...)" inside the Expanded class, it tells me that child isn't defined and I can't figure out what to do.

```
class _AppBarButton extends StatelessWidget {
   final String title;
  final Function onTap;
  const _AppBarButton({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Expanded(
        child: Text(  // this is where the child isn't defined.
          title,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Expanded` in a `Row`, `Column`, or `Flex` widget:  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error due to the Expanded widget.

> Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.

Either remove the Expanded Widget or Wrap the Expanded Widget with a Column or Row like the following code :

```
class _AppBarButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Function onTap;
  const _AppBarButton({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had it in a row originally and I only changed it to how I posted it because I wasn't sure if that was the issue. I'll make a new post because I can't post the original code here, but it gives me the same issue and in this one, the expanded class is in a row and there is a row in it that holds the _AppBarButton. I also tried putting flex around the row and I got the same error and I tried putting flex around the _AppBarButtons and it still gave me the same error. The odd thing is that although it has an error the expanded class is actually doing what it is supposed to in the app.

Comment: I was going to post the original code but I restarted VS code and the error disappeared, guess I forgot to do the old turning it off and on :)